# Issue in porting VC++ application to VS2008

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc

I had an application developed in VC++ that uses a third party dll which also is developed in VC++
It works fine, and when checked with dependency walker, the application and dll depends on MFC42.dll, MSVCRT.dll, MSVCP60.dll etc.

The application is now ported to VS2008, and there is no change in the code that invoke the dll.
Normal functionalities works fine after invoking the DLL functions

But while trying to invoke function with Dialog, like

```
MyFunc(void)
{
handle = AfxGetResourceHandle();
AfxSetResourceHandle(::GetModuleHandle(mydll));
if( myCDialog.DoModal() == IDOK )
{
/* My Functionality */
}
AfxSetResourceHandle(handle);
}
```

There is an error Access Violation in MFC42.dll (c0000005) while trying to execute DoModal.

The exe code is fine, as it can perfectly work with dll's made with VS2008 and higher.

Answer (score 2):

When you ported the application to VC-2008 there should no longer be a dependancy to MFC42.DLL. This is the MFC DLL from VC 6.0.

Maybe your codenow uses the VC-2008 MFC but your library uses the MFC from VC 6.0.
If both (the library and your code) share the MFC code this can't work.

PS: When switching the development Environment, make sure that all your 3rd Party libs also Support this Environment. May be you just Need a new lib file. Or if you have the source code you Need to rebuild the lib.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState())` to enable the MFC framework to handle the resources correctly.

```
extern "C" void WINAPI MyFunc(void)
{
  AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());
  if( myCDialog.DoModal() == IDOK )
  {
    /* My Functionality */
  }
}
```